# How to click text to change the value

Tags: jquery

How to click text(abc) and change input type value,"some text" to "abc"

```
<div id="click"> abc </div>
<input type="text" value="some text"/>

<script>
    $("#click").click(function () {



    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`text`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) to get the text within the `div`, and [`val`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) to change the value of the `input`:

```
$("#click").click(function() {
    $("input").val($(this).text());
});
```

You may want to make the `input` selector more specific though, as this would currently change the value of every `input` in the DOM.

Also note that this will include any white space in the new value. So for your example, the value would include a space before and after the text "abc". You could prevent that using [`trim`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/).

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/Nrg4R/14/) of the above.

Answer (score 3):

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 

          $('#click').click(function () { 
                $('input[type="text"]').val($(this).text());
             }); 
    });
```

---

try it out

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="click" onclick="functionName();"> abc </div>
<input type="text" value="some text" id="textChange"/>

<script>
    function functionName(){
         $('textChange').value = '';
         $('textChange').value = $('click').innerHTML;
    }
</script>
```

try this.